# Python package and command line

Tags: python

I have a python project that is essentially a set of scripts and tools, I'm packaging up like so:

```
myProject
    - bin/
        - sometasks/
            - task1.py
            - task2.py
        - someothertasks/
            - othertask1.py
            - othertask2.py
    - settings.py
    - etc.py
```

In order to run a task (or job, script, whatever) via a cronjob or from the command line, I run it like this:

```
python -m bin.sometasks.task1
```

It works fine, but I'm starting to encounter issues with relative imports when adding daemons to the mix such as Celery.

For example, trying to do

```
import myProject.etc #-or-# import .etc
```

Won't work since the root of the project within the daemon is now "sometasks" or one of my other sub-directories.

From what I understand I need to use some kind of root level script that can import and run the "tasks". I am assuming this is similar to how Django has the manage.py script.

Google seems to suggest using setuptools, but I was under the impression that was package distribution and this project is private.

What is the best practise for achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick (but kind of stupid) fix:

```
try:
    import myProject.etc #-or-# import .etc
except ImportError:
    import sys
    import os
    sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + '/../../')
    import myProject.etc #-or-# import .etc
```